# Neo4j matching two-circle or the start point

Tags: neo4j

Starting from the node (me), I want to match the following pattern:

```
(me)-[:FOLLOW]->(user:User)-[:FOLLOW]->(me)
```

Or

```
(me)
```

i.e. the start point itself.

How to write the Cypher query?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a person label and a property name with value 'me':

```
MATCH (me:Person {name: 'me'})-[:FOLLOW]->(:User)-[:FOLLOW]->(me)
RETURN *
```